# jquery ui tooltip closes if select gets clicked

Tags: jquery-ui, select, tooltip

I have a jQuery UI tooltip and whenever I click the select inside of the tooltip it closes the tooltip.

Maybe it's related to this: [mouseenter mouseleave and a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781518/mouseenter-mouseleave-and-a-select)

this doesn't work:
`$(".select_test").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
});`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bXxdH/2/

I know that it is clearly visible that the select is bigger expanded than the tooltip high is.

Here is a screenshot from my site: http://prntscr.com/1dvgy3
It is also happening on my site even though the select is not too big.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't close with me (in chrome). It closes when mouse leaves the tooltip, but not when  i make a selection.

Comment: I'm using Firefox (22) and it is behaving very weird.
And in the IE the Fiddle doesn't even work for me..

Comment: Ok, I've just tested it in my Chrome and you are right, works as expected in Chrome, but not in Firefox and not at all in the IE...
Can someone help me?